# Not getting change events when radio buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

Mates,
I'm tryin' to set backbone events when radio buttons are clicked.
I have the following buttons:

```
<p><label for="pays">Pays now</label><input id="pays" name="pays" type="radio" value="1" class="_100"/></p>
<p><label for="pays2">Pays later</label><input id="pays2" name="pays" type="radio" value="2" class="_100"/>
```

And I define the event like this:

```
'click input[name=pays]:not(:checked)': 'radioChecked'
```

So, as I understand it, it should fire when clicking an input named pays that's not checked.

The thing is, that is not firing any event when I click on a radio button.

If I try this...

```
'click input[name=pays]': radioClicked
```

I can fix this with some flags, but i'll have the event fired every time any radio is clicked.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution.
I changed the event declaration to:

```
'click input[name=pays]:checked': 'onRadioClick'
```

So now it triggers when I click on any radio button named pays, and if I use:

```
$('input[name=pays]:checked').val()
```

I get the checked radio value, instead of the first one declarated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not fully understanding but seems as though this should work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="pays"]').click(function () {
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            // do something here
            console.log('i am checked');
        }
    });
});
// .prop available in jQuery 1.6 or above.
```

Comment: so why didn't u fix it...lol. I did thx, good lookin out bro.

Comment: `.on()` is only available in jQuery 1.7+; as a side-note `this.checked` is faster and shorter than `$(this).prop('checked')`

Comment: actually no prop is 1.6 as I stated. that is what I was referring to. not ".on".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is from your View.Try to put quotes around **radio** handler.

```
'click input[name=pays]': radioHandler
```

And one advice: I had trouble with tutorials that uses older Backbone varsions ( < 0.9 ). So check your Backbone version.